# Make a function interface async without copy and paste

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-loader

Webpack provides a TypeScript interface for implementing a loader:

```
import { loader } from "webpack";

namespace loader {
  interface Loader extends Function {
      (this: LoaderContext, source: string | Buffer, sourceMap?: RawSourceMap): string | Buffer | void | undefined;
      pitch?(remainingRequest: string, precedingRequest: string, data: any): any;
      raw?: boolean;
  }
}
```

So when I implement that I do

```
const sfcLoader: loader.Loader = function(source: string) {
  /* ... */
};
```

Now I am trying to create an interface that *is that* interface but returns a Promise:

```
const sfcLoader /* : loader.Loader */ = async function(source: string) {
  /* await ... */
};
```

*Note that `async`*

Of course I don't want to copy and paste that interface. Is there a way I can extend (or something) and modify the interface from webpack?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a mapped type based on your loader interface. The idea is that you need to use the keyword `infer` to get access to the existing return type of the function. In your case, you'd need to wrap the return type into a `Promise`, I guess. Try this code sample in TypeScript Playground (we wrote it for the book "TypeScript Quickly"):

```
type ReturnPromise<T> =
    T extends (...args: infer A) => infer R ? (...args: A) => Promise<R> : T;   

type Promisify<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: ReturnPromise<T[P]>;
};

interface SyncService {
    baseUrl: string; 
    getA(): string;
}

class AsyncService implements Promisify<SyncService> {
    baseUrl: string; 

    getA(): Promise<string> {
        return Promise.resolve('');
    }
}

let service = new AsyncService();


let result = service.getA(); // hover over result: it's of type Promise<string>
```

Here, we declare a new type `Promisify<T>`.  To test it, we take the interface `SyncService`, find its properties that are methods (`getA()` in this case), and wrap its return type into `Promise`.